# DFS + Memoized solution getting TLE on LeetCode

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I was trying to solve this problem in a contest(now completed) [on LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/loud-and-rich/description/).

> In a group of N people (labelled 0, 1, 2, ..., N-1), each person has
>   different amounts of money, and different levels of quietness.
>
> For convenience, we'll call the person with label x, simply "person
>   x".
>
> We'll say that richer[i] = [x, y] if person x definitely has more
>   money than person y.  Note that richer may only be a subset of valid
>   observations.
>
> Also, we'll say quiet[x] = q if person x has quietness q.
>
> Now, return answer, where answer[x] = y if y is the least quiet person
>   (that is, the person y with the smallest value of quiet[y]), among all
>   people who definitely have equal to or more money than person x.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: richer = [[1,0],[2,1],[3,1],[3,7],[4,3],[5,3],[6,3]], quiet =
>   [3,2,5,4,6,1,7,0] Output: [5,5,2,5,4,5,6,7] Explanation:  answer[0] =
>   5. Person 5 has more money than 3, which has more money than 1, which has more money than 0. The only person who is quieter (has lower
>   quiet[x]) is person 7, but it isn't clear if they have more money than
>   person 0.
>
> answer[7] = 7. Among all people that definitely have equal to or more
>   money than person 7 (which could be persons 3, 4, 5, 6, or 7), the
>   person who is the quietest (has lower quiet[x]) is person 7.
>
> The other answers can be filled out with similar reasoning.

There are no cycles in the input.

This look like a straightforward DFS problem where we keep track of the `quietness` of the nodes in the path.

And my solution is this

```
class Solution {
 public:
  int doDFS(unordered_map<int, bool>& visited,
            unordered_map<int, vector<int> > graph, vector<int>& quiet,
            vector<int>& answer, int current) {
    if (visited.find(current) != visited.end()) {
      return answer[current];
    }
    int current_min = current;
    for (int i = 0; i < graph[current].size(); ++i) {
      int min_y = doDFS(visited, graph, quiet, answer, graph[current][i]);
      if (quiet[current_min] > quiet[min_y]) {
        current_min = min_y;
      }
    }
    answer[current] = current_min;
    visited[current] = true;
    return answer[current];
  }
  vector<int> loudAndRich(vector<vector<int> >& richer, vector<int>& quiet) {
    // vector<vector<int>> graph(quiet.size(), vector<int>());
    unordered_map<int, vector<int> > graph;
    vector<int> answer(quiet.size());
    unordered_map<int, bool> visited;
    for (int i = 0; i < richer.size(); ++i) {
      // cout << richer[i][1] << ' ' << richer[i][0] << endl;
      if (graph.find(richer[i][1]) == graph.end()) {
        graph.insert({richer[i][1], vector<int>{richer[i][0]}});
      } else {
        graph[richer[i][1]].push_back(richer[i][0]);
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < quiet.size(); ++i) {
      if (visited.find(i) == visited.end()) {
        doDFS(visited, graph, quiet, answer, i);
      }
    }

    return answer;
  }
};
```

But I'm not able to get this accepted it gets timed out for larger input. 
The runtime of this solution is `O(N)` as we visit each node only once.

Could someone help me as to why this is getting timed out?

Comment: visited[current] = true; should be the first thing you do

Comment: @juvian Good catch. But, even with this change, it still doesn't get accepted.

Comment: Every "heavy" object is passed by reference except for `graph`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Nope, I missed that out. Didn't realize that it'd have such an impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `unordered_map<int, vector<int> > graph` to `unordered_map<int, vector<int> > &graph`, you are making a copy on each call which is giving you tle. With that change, it gets accepted.

Comment: missed an accept in the contest by literally one character. Thank you.

Comment: @thebenman a pity. I usually put these variables global to avoid having this issue